# ¿Cómo sincronizar la ejecución de código cuando hay mas de un proceso?

Tags: java

Necesito establecer un mecanismo de control de ejecución de procesos.

Para ello había pensado que lo mejor es crear un método synchronized para garantizar que solo un proceso está ejecutando ese método a la vez.

```
public synchronized BasicDBObject manageExecution(String process, String objectId, boolean finish)
```

El problema es que hago más de una instancia de esta clase ( una por hilo), por lo que más de un proceso puede invocar al método synchronized, perdiendo todo el sentido.

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Había pensado usar el patrón Singleton para conseguir una única instancia de la clase en toda la aplicación, pero sigo sin ver como asegurar que solo un proceso ejecute el método.

Muchas gracias

EDITO:

Patrón Singleton con método synchronized

```
    public enum testInteger {
    CONNECTION;
    private static Integer numero = null;


    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public synchronized Integer getNumero(Integer n) {

        if (numero == null){
            numero = new Integer(0);
        }
          numero += n;
        return numero;
    }
}
```

Main 1

```
System.out.println(testInteger.CONNECTION.getNumero(new Integer(1000)));
```

Main 2

```
System.out.println(testInteger.CONNECTION.getNumero(new Integer(5)));
```

El problema es que cada uno ejecuta el método sin que synchronized bloquee al segundo que trata de usarlo.

**Comentarios adicionales de OP:**

Trato de explicarme. Tengo una app bacth de java, y distintos sh que invocan parte del código de esta app. El problema es que quiero que antes de que cada sh, haga su código correspondiente, le pregunte a un método si puede hacerlo o no. Si yo no garantizo que solo un proceso puede ejecutar ese método a la vez, las respuestas pueden ser inconsistentes. Por eso cree un método "synchronized" en la clase ProccesController. El problema es que si instancio un objeto de esta clase en cada proceso, el synchronized no sirve para nada.

Comment: Que hace exactamente el metodo `manageExecution`? Leer archivos? Lee base de datos?

Comment: lee de base de datos, y le indica al método que ha invocado si se puede ejecutar o debe esperar. Ese proceso hará un Thread.sleep(ms) y volverá a invocar al synchronized hasta que éste le devuelva que puede ejecutarse

Comment: Cuando hablas de *proceso*, ¿a qué te refieres? ¿A un hilo, o de verdad un proceso del sistema operativo?

Comment: Trato de explicarme. Tengo una app bacth de java, y distintos sh que invocan parte del código de esta app. El problema es que quiero que antes de que cada sh, haga su código correspondiente, le pregunte a un método si puede hacerlo o no. Si yo no garantizo que solo un proceso puede ejecutar ese método a la vez, las respuestas pueden ser inconsistentes. Por eso cree un método "synchronized" en la clase ProccesController. El problema es que si instancio un objeto de esta clase en cada proceso, el synchronized no sirve para nada.

Comment: Te dejo una pista... en efecto, los locks de java no te van a servir para controlar el acceso de varios process. La mejor idea que se me ocurre es de usar un archivo en el file system par servirte de lock. O sea, algo como, al ejecutar el método, comienzas por tratar de crear un archivo "lock". Si funciona, sigues adelante y borras el archivo al terminar. Si falla, es porque el archivo ya existe, e indica que otro proceso está ejecutando el método. En fin, es solo la idea general que puedes ajustar según tus necesidades.

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizas de manera correcta el patrón singleton podrías lograr que todos tus hilos utilicen sincronizadamente dicho método. Para realizar esta prueba vamos a necesitar una implementación de un singleton, un ejecutor que se corra al momento de iniciar un hilo y un main que pruebe lo que sucede.
Este es mi modelo.

```
public class Singleton {

private static Singleton instancia;
private Integer numero;

public static Singleton getInstancia() {
    if (instancia == null)
        crearInstancia();

    return instancia;
}

private static void crearInstancia() {
    synchronized(Singleton.class) {
        if (instancia == null)
            instancia = new Singleton();
    }
}

private Singleton() {
    this.numero = 0;
}

public synchronized Integer getNuevoNumero(Integer agregado) {
    this.numero += agregado;
    return numero;
}
```

}

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Ejecutor implements Runnable {

private String nombreHilo;
private Integer numero;

public Ejecutor(String nombreHilo, Integer numero) {
    this.nombreHilo = nombreHilo;
    this.numero = numero;
}



@Override
public void run() {

    System.out.println("Hora de ejecucion de " + this.nombreHilo + ": " + new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").format(new Date()));
    System.out.println("El nuevo numero es: " + Singleton.getInstancia().getNuevoNumero(this.numero));
    System.out.println("Hora de finalización de " + this.nombreHilo + ": " + new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").format(new Date()));

}
```

}

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Thread h1 = new Thread(new Ejecutor("h1", 5));
    h1.start();

    Thread h2 = new Thread(new Ejecutor("h2", 10));
    h2.start();

    try {
        h1.join();
        h2.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.exit(0);
}
```

}

**Resultado:**

Hora de ejecucion de h1: 11:28:53 
Hora de ejecucion de h2: 11:28:53 
El nuevo numero es: 5 
Hora de finalización de h1: 11:28:58 
El nuevo numero es: 15 
Hora de finalización de h2: 11:29:03

Análisis: Si analizamos el resultado, los dos hilos corren simultaneamente, el hilo h1 arranca su ejecucion ni bien corre y el hilo h2 espera que el h1 termine (eso es lo que hace la sincronizacion). Una vez que h1 termina, h2 sincroniza y ejecuta la consulta. Por otra parte,el patrón singleton mantiene su estado y agrega el valor nuevo.

Comment: El problema de OP es que quiere sincronizar mas de un proceso, no simplemente hilos de un solo proceso. En este caso, un singleton típico no funciona.

Comment: Si vos quisieras sincronizar más de un proceso que esté contemplado dentro de tu clase Singleton, con tan solo sincronizar el llamado a la instancia, lográs ese freno en ese lugar.

Answer (score 0):

Si haces más de una instancia, el synchronized pierde sentido.

Quizás lo que te interese sea crear los métodos, además de synchronized, que sean static. De esa manera los métodos son independientes de la instancia.

Comment: La garantía más importante del `static` que deberías mencionar es que solamente puede haber una referencia, y de esa manesa se evita que cada instancia llame a su versión del método que mantiene su propio valor interno del número por la restricción de que un método estático solamente puede acceder a variables estáticas.